# how do I debug my name server setup on hosted server?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, reverse-dns

bind9 is running with no reported errors but after 24 hours I am failing to see the domain name propagated.

There is one error in the syslog'd start of bind9; would this be enough to prevent propagation? It occurs after bind9 is reported as running OK.

I don't really know what to look for to pinpoint what is not right -- mistakes in my configuration or .... should I host my primary master on XName's name servers ... I'd be grateful for any answers which help me understand what to look for. Many thanks!

I need control over my server's zone records to add SRV resource records Kerberos and LDAP and TXT records for DKIM and SPF.

My Ubuntu 12.04 server is running on a Cloud Server from 1&1 on which I run several Drupal websites that send out lots of emails for two not-for-profit organisations. I use 1&1's name servers to resolve access to the websites but need control over zone files for a new domain name that I registered through 1&1. The new domain is `misfits-server.co.uk`; it has rDNS 82.165.46.221 set by 1&1 (I don't understand exactly how this might interfere with my bind9 setup). I have a subdomain `ns1.misfits-server.co.uk` with rDNS 87.106.252.71 set via 1&1's Control Panel.

I have opted to use *my* name server instead of 1&1's by telling their Control Panel whose "DNS Check" reports:

```
    Domain name :   misfits-server.co.uk
    IP Address (A-Record) : 
    Name server 1:  ns0.xname.org
    Name server 2:  ns1.misfits-server.co.uk
    Name server 3:  ns2.xname.org
    Name server 4:  ns1.xname.org
```

(these are the name servers I specified but not in the order in which I specified them to 1&1)

This is my zone file for the new domain name:

```
;
; BIND data file for misfits-server.co.uk
;
@ 1D    IN      SOA     ns1.misfits-server.co.uk hostmaster.misfits-server.co.uk. (
                        2012053101      ; Serial
                        3H              ; Refresh
                        15              ; Retry
                        4W              ; Expire
                        1D)             ; Negative Cache TTL
;
; main name servers
        IN      NS      ns1.misfits-server.co.uk.
; mail domain mail server 
        IN      MX      10      mail.misfits-server.co.uk.
; A records for misfits-server.co.uk and name servers
@       IN      A       82.165.46.221
ns1     IN      A       87.106.252.71
; subdomains
mail    IN      A       82.165.46.221
coombe  IN      A       82.165.46.221

; XName secondary name servers
misfits-server.co.uk.  IN       NS      ns0.xname.org.
misfits-server.co.uk.  IN       NS      ns1.xname.org.
misfits-server.co.uk.  IN       NS      ns2.xname.org.

; service.protocol.realm            class       SRV     priority        weight  port    target
_kerberos._udp.misfits-server.co.uk.    IN      SRV     0               0       88         misfits-server.co\
.uk.

.... etc ...  

; service.name                     class        TXT     realm
_kerberos.misfits-server.co.uk.               IN        TXT     MISFITS-SERVER.CO.UK
```

reverse DNS zone files:

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for misfits-server.co.uk 82.165.46.221
;
@ 1D    IN      SOA     ns1.misfits-server.co.uk hostmaster.misfits-server.co.uk. (
                        2012053103      ; Serial
                        3H              ; Refresh
                        15              ; Retry
                        4W              ; Expire
                        1D)             ; Negative Cache TTL
;
        IN      NS      ns1.misfits-server.co.uk.
        IN      NS      ns0.xname.org.
        IN      NS      ns1.xname.org.
        IN      NS      ns2.xname.org.
;
1       IN      PTR     misfits-server.co.uk.
2       IN      PTR     mail.misfits-server.co.uk.
3       IN      PTR     coombe.misfits-server.co.uk.
```

and:

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for ns1.misfits-server.co.uk 87.106.252.71
;
@ 1D    IN      SOA     ns1.misfits-server.co.uk hostmaster.misfits-server.co.uk. (
                        2012053103      ; Serial
                        3H              ; Refresh
                        15              ; Retry
                        4W              ; Expire
                        1D)             ; Negative Cache TTL
;
        IN      NS      ns1.misfits-server.co.uk.
        IN      NS      ns0.xname.org.
        IN      NS      ns1.xname.org.
        IN      NS      ns2.xname.org. 
;
1       IN      PTR     ns1.misfits-server.co.uk.
```

bind is listening; but the domain naes, although valid, do not include `misfits-server.co.uk`

```
# netstat -tap
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name 
tcp        0      0 *:mysql                 *:*                     LISTEN      1202/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 *:kerberos-adm          *:*                     LISTEN      1330/kadmind    
tcp        0      0 *:http                  *:*                     LISTEN      1703/apache2
```

and syslog seemed ok to me although I don't recognise `ns3.xtremeweb.de` as anything I've specified:

```
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: found 1 CPU, using 1 worker thread
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: using up to 4096 sockets
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: loading configuration from '/etc/bind/named.conf'
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: reading built-in trusted keys from file '/etc/bind/bind.keys'
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: using default UDP/IPv4 port range: [1024, 65535]
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: using default UDP/IPv6 port range: [1024, 65535]
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: no IPv6 interfaces found
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: listening on IPv4 interface lo, 127.0.0.1#53
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: listening on IPv4 interface eth0, 82.165.46.221#53
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: listening on IPv4 interface eth0:0, 87.106.245.98#53
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: generating session key for dynamic DNS
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: sizing zone task pool based on 8 zones
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: using built-in root key for view _default
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: set up managed keys zone for view _default, file 'managed-keys.bind'
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: command channel listening on 127.0.0.1#953
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: /etc/bind/db.82:11: using RFC1035 TTL semantics
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: zone 46.165.82.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 2012053103
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: /etc/bind/db.87:11: using RFC1035 TTL semantics
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: zone 252.106.87.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 2012053103
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: /etc/bind/db.misfits-server.co.uk:12: using RFC1035 TTL semantics
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: zone misfits-server.co.uk/IN: loaded serial 2012053101
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: managed-keys-zone ./IN: loaded serial 4
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: running
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: zone 46.165.82.in-addr.arpa/IN: sending notifies (serial 2012053103)
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: zone misfits-server.co.uk/IN: sending notifies (serial    2012053101)
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: zone 252.106.87.in-addr.arpa/IN: sending notifies (serial 2012053103)
May 31 13:33:03 coombe named[2389]: error (unexpected RCODE SERVFAIL) resolving 'ns3.xtremeweb.de/A/IN': 213.239.192.240#53


tcp        0      0 *:kpasswd               *:*                     LISTEN      1330/kadmind    
tcp        0      0 villagenet.org.u:domain *:*                     LISTEN      2389/named      
tcp        0      0 s15917281.online:domain *:*                     LISTEN      2389/named      
tcp        0      0 localhost.locald:domain *:*                     LISTEN      2389/named      
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN      662/sshd
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the level of experience your question and current configuration suggests, I ***STRONGLY*** advise you to contact either 1&1 or xname and have them assist you with configuring your DNS.
As it stands right now your configuration is badly broken (nothing in your domain is resolving from my workstation), and it's beyond the scope of a Q&A site to straighten it out.

If you want to slug through this yourself you need to **`STOP`** right now, go to the bookstore (amazon.com, the O'Reilly website, whatever), and acquire a copy of [DNS and BIND](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100575.do).

Read this book cover to cover before attempting ANY further DNS-related activities.
It should be considered mandatory reading for anyone setting up any kind of DNS infrastructure (and a good idea for everyone else too!).

---

Regarding your configuration: Your DNS is currently set up such that both xname.com's name servers and `ns1.misfits-server.co.uk` are authoritative for your domain.  This is almost certainly not what you want.

Additionally I see the following problems with your environment as it stands right now:

1. You seem unclear on whether you want to host your domain on *your server* or outsource it to xname.
   (You really need to make this decision *first*)
2. There appears to be no glue record for `ns1.misfits-server.co.uk`.
   (If you want to use your own server (within the domain) for DNS hosting you need to set up glue records, this is typically done through your domain registrar.)
3. `xname.org`'s name servers don't think they're authoritative for your domain.
   (Name servers don't magically know how to answer queries - If you want to use xname's servers you need to work with xname to get them set up.)
4. You appear to be creating reverse zones. This probably isn't your responsibility.
   (Talk to the ISP that gave you the IP addresses and see what their procedures are.)

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. Yes, I have "DNS and BIND" and am working my way through it. I appreciate your advice - you have given me some useful pointers.